# The command exited with code 3 error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I converted a project to VS2015 from VS2012 I think. Now I get the following error and its the first time getting it so I'm a bit lost on how to solve it or what the cause is.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMERGE.EXE" /t:console  /targetplatform:v4,%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /out:BlobClient.exe StrikeMedia.BlobStorage.CmdLineTool.exe StrikeMedia.ServiceBus.dll StrikeMedia.BlobStorage.dll" exited with code 3.  StrikeMedia.BlobStorage.CmdLineTool

Hope you can assist me on this.

Thanks

Comment: It can be caused by a number of issues, but first thing I would try is to clean the project and rebuild. Try it from command line msbuild /t:clean <solutionname>

Comment: I found what the issue was. I didn't had ILMerge install on my machine. Thanks

Comment: Glad you found the problem. If you found it though increasing verbose output or it got printed out on command line, sharing your steps as an answer here might help someone else in similar situation :)

Comment: I've added a basic one you may edit it with more information or correct if wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Adding an answer so someone else who might be having similar issues get help.

The last part of the error points to the issue.

> exited with code 3

which is listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) as

> ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND 3 (0x3) The system cannot find the path
>   specified.

As you later found out the ILMerge was not installed on the machine after which the error was gone.

Comment: Thanks!  I love it when the answer to a [closed] question proves to be helpful.

Comment: In Delphi, I got similar issue. But when I ran same command from commandline prompt, it worked.